# Add simple slide down animation to "read more" text reveal

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I have this nifty snippet of code that adds a "read more" & "read less" to the end of my text, Allowing the visible text to expand and contract.

I was trying to add an animation to this.. So it slides down and up instead of just being an instant change..

I tried adding `.slidDown` and `.slideUp` in multiple sections. But it either didnt work or hid the entire content.

I also attempted to add `transition: all 0.5s ease;` for the content wrapper but that also didnt create a transition.

Any help is much appreciated!

**[WORKING JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SZLgs/22/)**

Comment: For this to work you need to refactor the whole snippet as right know it does not hide content but replaces content (which cannot be animated). You would need to set the whole content, have the content div be at a certain height (e.g. one line) and then animate the div.

Answer (score 8):

I would potentially look at using `slideToggle()` in order to create this.

The below will get you started in terms of a situation how the `slideToggle` could work but you can integrate your version of read more/less into it to potentially get it working.

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( ".content" ).slideToggle( "fast" );
      var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass("open");

        if ($this.hasClass("open")) {
            $this.html("Less");
        } else {
            $this.html("Read more");
        }
});
```

```css
.content {
display:none;
}
p {
margin:0 0 10px;
}
button {
margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summary"><p>This is your summary content...</p></div>
<div class="content">
<p>
  This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You
  should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
  your life.  Congratulations!
</p>
</div>
<button>Read more</button>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wish i could use this method but its for a wordpress install and I have no control over the html. As its for product descriptions and needs to have a global effect.

Comment: If it's Wordpress, you could use the_excerpt() as your summary and the_content() would be your content that you'd be able to use the slideToggle() on. When you say you have no control over the html, are you not able to access the theme files?

Comment: Brilliant, hopefully then you'll be able to integrate the above

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a plugin for this?

[Readmore.js](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/) seems to do the job perfectly and has many options for customization.

```js
var lineHeight = 20;
var lines = 2;

$('.content').readmore({
  speed: 1000,
  collapsedHeight: lineHeight * lines
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
 }
  

.content {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam suscipit veniam non <a href="#">magni similique</a>. Asperiores aut sapiente nobis porro ad provident eveniet eos aspernatur quidem iusto! Dolorum libero porro animi.</p>
  <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente aperiam voluptas mollitia laboriosam delectus <strong>possimus minus quaerat culpa</strong> eos corporis tenetur ducimus quo incidunt aspernatur doloremque unde nihil. Quis quaerat!</p>
  <p>Ea iusto obcaecati cumque quae numquam minima laboriosam porro sit a animi reprehenderit eveniet saepe aperiam optio nemo eos et. Eaque perferendis.</p>
</div>

<!-- jQuery 2.1.1 -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Readmore.js -->
<script src="https://fastcdn.org/Readmore.js/2.1.0/readmore.min.js"></script>
```